# Inter VM communication in a single Cloud Service

Tags: azure, networking

After spending a good amount of time in the Azure documentation. It seems that there is an inconsistency regarding the ability for VMs in the same cloud service (not in a VNet) to talk to each other. Through experience I know that the VMs can talk to each other but it almost seems like not guaranteed behavior.

[Virtual Network Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj156007.aspx) is especially unhelpful because it says "Do your VMs or cloud services need to communicate with each other within Azure." This make it seem like any two VMs need a VNet to communicate internally. Would it be better to state "VMs in separate cloud servers"? Another similar statement is in [How to Connect Virtual Machines with a Virtual Network or Cloud Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-connect-virtual-machine/) which was changed a day ago and previously said VMs in a single cloud service could talk to each other.

On the other hand, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances/ implies that intra cloud service communication is possible. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-load-balance/ states this too.

It seems to be a possibility that cloud services will eventually have VNets by default and that these inconsistencies may lay some truth to that.

It would be nice to get a final answer on this and have it be documented. Regardless of VNets being a best practice, it's a valid to concern to know if you can communicate between VMs in a cloud service without a VNet on a guaranteed basis.

EDIT: Moved to ServerFault: see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/666778/inter-vm-communication-in-a-single-cloud-service).

Comment: If you don't have a VNet setup with private IP address space how would you propose the VMs talk with each other? They are only addressable at that point via their shared wrapper Cloud Service which presents load balanced public Endpoints which makes it hard to address a single Instance without assigning a custom Endpoint (PAT) mapping.

Comment: Each of the VMs within the Cloud Service (No VNet, just region) receive a DIP and I've been able to communicate between them with that DIP. I also went on to test if it's possible to do that inter cloud service without VNets and it's not possible as expected. The VMs are also able to resolve the correct DIP of their respective VM Name/Hostnames by using the same search domain <VM Name>.<Cloud Service Name>.<internal ns>.cloudapp.net.

Comment: @SimonW - this is simply not true. VMs within a cloud service may absolutely communicate between themselves, with no need for public endpoint. Virtual Machines have free reign across all ports on all other VMs within the cloud service (unless firewalls are enabled on individual VMs). web/worker role instances within a cloud service must use internal endpoints for communication.

Comment: Regardless: This question will likely be closed here since it's not programming-related. It needs to be posted to ServerFault.

Comment: I stand corrected :).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'll repost thanks